# CodeChef Practice Challenge - "ATM"

Tags: python, python-3.x

> Pooja would like to withdraw `X` $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if `X` is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.
>
> #### Input
>
> Positive integer 0 < `X` <= 2000 - the amount of cash which Pooja wishes to withdraw.
>
> Nonnegative number 0<= `Y` <= 2000 with two digits of precision - Pooja's initial account balance.
>
> #### Output
>
> Output the account balance after the attempted transaction, given as a number with two digits of precision. If there is not enough money in the account to complete the transaction, output the current bank balance.
>
> #### Example - Successful Transaction
>
> Input: 30 120.00
>
> Output: 89.50
>
> #### Example - Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)
>
> Input: 42 120.00
>
> Output: 120.00
>
> #### Example - Insufficient Funds
>
> Input: 300 120.00
>
> Output: 120.00

I used Python3.x to solve this program and my code is this:-

```
withdrawal_amount, balance_amount = input().split()              
withdrawal_amount = int(withdrawal_amount)                        
balance_amount = float(balance_amount)                            
if withdrawal_amount % 5 == 0:
    balance_amount = balance_amount - withdrawal_amount - 0.5     
    print('%.2f' % balance_amount)
else:
    print('%.2f' % balance_amount)
```

It is executing perfectly but when I submitted the answer and the result was incorrect. Can anyone help me and tell me where I'm wrong.

Question link: https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing one condition here that is if `withdrawal_amount > balance_amount`. Modify your code to this and try again

```
withdrawal_amount, balance_amount = input().split()              
withdrawal_amount = int(withdrawal_amount)                        
balance_amount = float(balance_amount)                            
if (withdrawal_amount % 5 == 0 and balance_amount>(withdrawal_amount+.5)):
    balance_amount = balance_amount - withdrawal_amount - 0.5     
    print('%.2f' % balance_amount)
else:
    print('%.2f' % balance_amount)
```

Comment: That is right, then should I add and condition where im checking if its multiple of 5 or not? or before the if condition?

Comment: add with the multiple of 5 or not condition as i did in answer

Comment: I added one more if statement before checking is it multiple of 5 or not and then submitted it still says wrong answer.

Comment: @AbhishekTripathi try to submit the code i have added in answer and tell if it is getting submitteed or not

Answer (score 0):

It could have missing Statements.
Try with proper statements quotation.
Modify your code with this and try again:

```
X,Y=map(float,input().split())
if X%5!=0:
    print("Incorrect Withdrawal Amount (not multiple of 5)")
elif (X%5==0) and (X>Y-0.5):
    print("Insufficient Funds")
else :
    print("Successful Transaction\n")
    print(round((Y-X-0.50),2))
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
withdrawal_amount, balance_amount = input().split()              
withdrawal_amount = int(withdrawal_amount)                        
balance_amount = float(balance_amount)                            
if (withdrawal_amount % 5 == 0 and balance_amount>=(withdrawal_amount+0.5)):
    balance_amount = balance_amount - withdrawal_amount - 0.5     
    print(round(balance_amount,2))
else:
    print(round(balance_amount,2))
```

Comment: As per the question,  if the withdrawal amount is as equal as balance amount the tax can't be deducted by the bank. Taking into account we can consider that the balance amount can either be greater than OR equal to (withdrawal_amount  + tax )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
inp_str = input().split(' ')

wtd_amnt = int(inp_str[0])
bal_amnt = float(inp_str[1])

lst_dgt = float(inp_str[0][len(inp_str[0]) - 1])


if lst_dgt in (5, 0) and wtd_amnt != 0:
    if wtd_amnt + 0.5 <= bal_amnt :
        print('%.2f' %(bal_amnt - wtd_amnt - 0.5))
    else: print('%.2f' %(bal_amnt))
else: print('%.2f' %(bal_amnt))
```

If the withdrawal amount + 0.5 = balance amount, then the output should be 0.00 i.e. 105 105.5 should give an output of 0.00.

Answer (score 0):

```
withdraw,balance = map(str,input().split())
withdraw =int(withdraw)
balance = float(balance)
if withdraw%5==0 and withdraw+0.50<=balance:
    print(balance-withdraw-0.50)
else:
    print(balance)
```

Comment: `input` already returns a string so the `map(str, ...)` is not necessary. You could just do `map(float, ...)` and remove the following 2 lines...